# Spark job taking long time # Code or Environment Issue?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

we have a 300 node cluster, each node having 132gb memory and 20 cores. the ask is - remove data from tableA which is in tableB and then merge B with A and push A to teradata.

below is the code

```
val ofitemp = sqlContext.sql("select * from B")
val ofifinal = sqlContext.sql("select * from A")
val selectfromfinal = sqlContext.sql("select A.a,A.b,A.c...A.x from A where A.x=B.x")
val takefromfinal = ofifinal.except(selectfromfinal)
val tempfinal = takefromfinal.unionAll(ofitemp)tempfinal.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("C")
val tempTableFinal = sqlContext.table("C")tempTableFinal.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("A")
```

the config used to run spark is -

```
EXECUTOR_MEM="16G"
HIVE_MAPPER_HEAP=2048   ## MB
NUMBER_OF_EXECUTORS="25"
DRIVER_MEM="5G"
EXECUTOR_CORES="3"
```

with A and B having few million records, the job is taking several hours to run.
As am very new to Spark, am not understanding - is it the code issue or the environment setting issue.

would be obliged, if you can share your thoughts to overcome the performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `except`could be a bottleneck because it compares all columns for equality. Is this really what you need (I'm confused about the join À.x=B.y`in the line before)

If you only need to check on 1 attribute, the fastest way would be to do a "leftanti"-join :

```
val takefromfinal = ofifinal.join(ofitemp,$"A.x"===$"B.y","leftanti")
```

Besides that, study spark-UI and identify the bottleneck